# Can you explain SQLwise why this INSERT statement only gets run if the SELECT statement fails? (rails first_or_create)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was looking at the Rails guides and came across [the section on active record's first_or_create method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#first_or_create).  It stated that the following code:

```
Client.where(:first_name => 'Andy').first_or_create(:locked => false)
# => #<Client id: 1, first_name: "Andy", orders_count: 0, locked: false, created_at: "2011-08-30 06:09:27", updated_at: "2011-08-30 06:09:27">
```

Would produce the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE (clients.first_name = 'Andy') LIMIT 1
BEGIN
INSERT INTO clients (created_at, first_name, locked, orders_count, updated_at) VALUES ('2011-08-30 05:22:57', 'Andy', 0, NULL, '2011-08-30 05:22:57')
COMMIT
```

I understand what the first_or_create does when used, my question . . .

**From the perspective of the SQL statement.  Why does the Insert statement get run only if the SELECT statement fails?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the point of the method. `first_or_create` will get the first record, or create one if there are no records that match the query. You can see that from the source code:

> ```
> # File activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb, line 117
> def first_or_create(attributes = nil, options = {}, &block)
>   first || create(attributes, options, &block)
> end
> ```

The `SELECT` statement finds all records that adhere to the `WHERE` clause, and that is limited to 1 record, hence `first`.

If that first record doesn't exist, it is created, hence the `INSERT` statement, and the `_or_create` part of the method name.

---

For the SQL statement itself, simply calling that would indeed create a new record every time. I think instead the docs are showing all the SQL that can be generated, with the understanding that first

`SELECT * FROM clients WHERE (clients.first_name = 'Andy') LIMIT 1`

is queried, and if nothing comes back, then the insertion

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO clients (created_at, first_name, locked, orders_count, updated_at) VALUES ('2011-08-30 05:22:57', 'Andy', 0, NULL, '2011-08-30 05:22:57')
COMMIT
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response AJ.  I understand how it works, my question is **why doesn't the insert statement execute every time**?  What stops the INSERT statement from being run unless the SELECT statement returns no records?

Comment: Indeed, how does this work SQLwise?  I edited the question to be more specific.

Comment: yeah i think its just the docs combining the two, I'd wait to see if someone weighs in with deep sql knowledge tho